# contenteditable div content out of width in firefox and IE9

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I want to make `contenteditable div` works like as it works on Chrome in firefox and chrome as if i dont hit `Enter` and keep pressing keys then content becomes overflow from div's width in Firefox(26 ver) and IE9 but in Chrome it automatically adjust in div's width here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  div {

  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div contenteditable="true"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

and i have created bin [here](http://jsbin.com/ixejECEG/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `word-wrap` property in css so it will work as expected.

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  word-wrap: break-word; /*Added property*/
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ajaPoCa/1/edit)</kbd>